# How to turn off postgresql function while deleting the type of that function

Tags: postgresql, function, types, dependencies, psql

I have a type called `export`

```
  Column   |     Type     | Modifiers
-----------+--------------+-----------
 date_time | text         |
 email     | text         |
 b1        | character(1) |
 b2        | character(1) |
 b3        | character(1) |
 b4        | character(1) |
 b5        | character(1) |
 b6        | character(1) |
 b7        | character(1) |
 b8        | character(1) |
 b9        | character(1) |
 b10       | character(1) |
 b11       | character(1) |
 b12       | character(1) |
 b13       | character(1) |
 b14       | character(1) |
 b15       | character(1) |
 b16       | character(1) |
 b17       | character(1) |
 b18       | character(1) |
 b19       | character(1) |
 b20       | character(1) |
 b21       | character(1) |
 b22       | character(1) |
 b23       | character(1) |
 b24       | character(1) |
 b25       | character(1) |
 b26       | character(1) |
 b27       | character(1) |
 b28       | character(1) |
 b29       | character(1) |
 b30       | character(1) |
 b31       | character(1) |
 b32       | character(1) |
 b33       | character(1) |
 b34       | character(1) |
 b35       | character(1) |
 b36       | character(1) |
 b37       | character(1) |
 b38       | character(1) |
 b39       | character(1) |
 b40       | character(1) |
 b41       | character(1) |
 b42       | character(1) |
 store     | text         |
 serie1    | text         |
 serie2    | text         |
 serie3    | text         |
 prod1     | text         |
 prod2     | text         |
 prod3     | text         |
```

And my function `example` returns this type. I would like to drop the type `export` and create a new one. But i have an error

```
ERROR:  cannot drop type export because other objects depend on it
```

So I used `CASCADE` and it deleted my function `example`. Can I disable the function for a moment while I drop the type? Or something?

My silly solution is: `drop type export` using `cascade`, create the new type `export` and run the script that creates my function `example` - but this is not what I want.

Maybe you have an idea how to disable this relation between function and type? Or how to insert attribute b43, b44, b45 ... every time I insert value into table?

Comment: "*drop type export using cascade, create new type export and run script that creates my function example*" - not silly at all. In fact that's the only solution to this problem.

Comment: thanks for responding :)